# will-change issue on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, will-change

I noticed that when I add `will-change` on a fixed button (using JS), it gets really choppy. This applies to both the 'will-change' button and the button without it.

Example that shows the issue: http://jsbin.com/kelajo/3/edit?html,css,js,output

GIF that shows the issue: http://i.imgur.com/sTSkvFA.gifv

Remove the `will-change` line and both buttons will start working.

Is this a Chrome issue, or am I missing anything? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This actually isn't the answer but I need to share it with the world:

I also had issues with `will-change` property, so i read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/will-change
It turns out, this property should be used very wisely:

> Be aware, that will-change may actually influence the visual
>   appearance of elements

Here is my problem: 
In this example, `will-change` property is messing with stacking-context (`z-index` overlapping elements). First element has this property and others don't (hover on dark div inside green div). It took me few hours to find out what was wrong with my code when i was trying to be fancy using `will-change`

```css
.will-change {
  will-change: opacity;  
}

.list {
  position: relative;
}
.list-element {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #308e74;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.list-element:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.hover-el {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
.hover-el:hover .show-on-hover {
  display: block;
}
.show-on-hover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #e6841e;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list-element will-change">
    <div class="hover-el">
      <div class="show-on-hover"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-element">
    <div class="hover-el">
      <div class="show-on-hover"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-element">
    <div class="hover-el">
      <div class="show-on-hover"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```